# How to create a new widget for a Paragraph field programmatically in an AJAX handler Drupal 8

Tags: php, ajax, drupal, drupal-8

I need to add Paragraph fields programmatically to an entity in an AJAX handler.

This is my AJAX callback:

```
function myAjaxCallback(array &$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormState $form_state)  {
  $paragraph3 = \Drupal\paragraphs\Entity\Paragraph::create([
    'type' => 'media',
    'field_caption' => 'Apart from the included Paragraph types, you can create your own simply by going to Structure -> Paragraphs types.',
  ]);
  $paragraph3->save();

  // Now I need to add $paragraph3 to $form['field_gallery_items']['widget']

  return $form;
}
```

I need to add the new Paragraph I created to the widget so that when the $form is returned I have added a paragraph.

How Can I do that?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm trying to do something similar where a user can upload a csv and then the it gets the csv contents and adds a parapgraph.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Append the Paragraph to the form Field

```
$form['field_gallery_items']['widget']->appendItem($paragraph3);
```